# Per Request Authorization using Facebook Login

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, oauth2

**Stack:** ASP.NET Core + Razor + SQLite

**TLDR:** How do I rely solely on Facebook Login for authorization?

I am building an app with sole integration to Facebook for my Facebook group. Essentially it is a "bidding" platform where ultimately the buyer & seller will communicate directly outside my app.

From my initial planning, the app only has a minimal state management on the client side (auth for creating & editing an entry or to place a bid).

Because of privacy & simplicity, I don't intend to implement Identity or store User entities, every entry or bid will be referenced to the FB userId; that should be the only identifying information that is stored in the DB.

I intend to authenticate every create/edit request with FB Login as a form of authorization. When viewing an entry, if the logged in user is the creator, an option to edit should appear.

A cursory research leads me to believe that it might not be suitable for me to use the Authorization functionality of ASP.NET Core and instead manually send a request to FB Login API to authenticate login status. I know that ASP.NET Core can save the access token retrieved from an external authentication, maybe I can reuse that?

Comment: Have you ever heard of OpenID Connect, OAuth, JSON Web Tokens (JWT), or federated authentication? Those are some base level concepts and technologies that you should explore first.